# How to create a single style for multiple mouse over events?

Tags: wpf, xaml, wpf-controls, wpf-style

I have four buttons and four text boxes where each button is linked to one of the textblocks. When the mouse is over the button I want the corresponding textblock to fade in (and out on mouse leave). There are plenty of examples of this showing a single button and textblock where you can simply bind a datatrigger to the button name in the textblock style.

Here's what I've got so far (all of this is in a textblock style):

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=UpdateButton, Path=IsMouseOver}" Value="True">
    <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
         <BeginStoryboard>
              <Storyboard TargetProperty ="Opacity" Duration="00:00:01">
                   <DoubleAnimation From="0" To="1" Duration="00:00:01"/>
              </Storyboard>
         </BeginStoryboard>
    </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
    <DataTrigger.ExitActions>
         <BeginStoryboard>
              <Storyboard TargetProperty ="Opacity" Duration="00:00:01">
                   <DoubleAnimation From="1" To="0" Duration="00:00:01"/>
              </Storyboard>
         </BeginStoryboard>
    </DataTrigger.ExitActions>
</DataTrigger>
```

As of right now, when I mouse over the Update Button, all of the textblocks show instead of just the one associated with the Update Button.

To fix this I could create styles for each textblock by their name and bind to the appropriate button, but this is a huge amount of repetition. I could likely used "BasedOn" to separate the button binding, but then we're still duplicating all of the code for the Storyboards and whatnot. But does anyone know a better way?

It would seem like there should be a way create this all in a single style using a single generic binding but link the specific buttons to their textblocks, so the button only triggers the Storyboard for it's linked textblock. Anyone know how to do this, or a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good way to handle this is to create a custom inherited `TextBlock` that can store reference to a button.

Example

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

//Custom TextBlock
public class SpecialTextBlock : TextBlock
{
    //This will be the button reference
    public Button BoundButton { get; set; }

    //Register the BoundButton as a dependency to allow binding
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ButtonProperty = DependencyProperty.Register
    (
        "BoundButton",
        typeof(Button),
        typeof(SpecialTextBlock),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(default(Button))
    );
}
```

Now that your new `SpecialTextBlock` is set up, you can create a new style for it. Use your original style, but apply it to `TargetType="local:SpecialTextBlock"` instead of `TargetType="TextBlock"`.

Then update your DataTrigger from your example within the style so that the trigger binds to itself (the `SpecialTextBlock`), and then looks at the referenced `Button` path.

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=BoundButton.IsMouseOver}" Value="True">
...
```

Now you are set up and can create your `TextBlocks` like so without having to restyle.

```
//Set your BoundButton binding to specify which button triggers the animation.
<local:SpecialTextBlock BoundButton="{Binding ElementName=UpdateButton}" />
```

Comment: It works! There is absolutely NO way I would have figured that out on my own. Coming from C++, WPF is a huge challenge in that there are so many different ways to do things, and yet none of them are obvious for the beginner.  Is there any special place to put the SpecialTextBlock class? I ended up putting it in App.xaml.cs but that was the first place VS didn't bark at me. Thank you so much Tronald!

Comment: Where you put it really depends on how you like to organize your information. You can create a new .cs file for it or put it in your Window or UserControl that's using it (within the namespace brackets, but outside the existing class brackets). As long as it's in your namespace, you can see it from anywhere. Don't worry, I started out in C++ too. WPF/C# is super easy in comparison, once you start getting used to it. You'll pick it up in no time!

Answer (score 0):

```
<StackPanel>
 <Button x:Name="MouseTarget"
     Content="Mouse Over This"
     />
 <Button Content="This one changes...">
  <Button.Style>
   <Style TargetType="Button">
    <Style.Triggers>
     <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=MouseTarget, Path=IsMouseOver}" Value="True">
      <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
     </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
   </Style>
  </Button.Style>
 </Button>
</StackPanel>
```